# How to customize the api version that appear in loopback 4 generated API explorer?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

Loopback 4 is showing a version number in the Api explorer and I'd like this version to follow the version of my component that is specified in the package.json .

How can this be achieved ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment, you can modify the spec manually. First get the application's OpenAPI spec by calling [`app.restServer.getApiSpec()`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/packages/rest/src/__tests__/integration/rest.application.integration.ts#L142)

Then modify the spec accordingly (change the `version` inside `info` to be the same as the `version` in package.json), and setting the new spec by calling [`app.api(your_new_spec)`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/packages/rest/src/__tests__/integration/rest.application.integration.ts#L131)

LoopBack team is building an OpenAPI spec enhancer service to make ^ automatically happen by applying spec enhancers. See the usage and demo documentation in [Extending-OpenAPI-specification](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Extending-OpenAPI-specification.html)

After finishing story [Adding an enhancer service in the rest server](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/4380), you will be able to modify the spec by applying your enhancer.